# Incomplete implementation - Xcode warning

Tags: ios

I have just started with iOS development and am a bit stuck due to a warning. The build is successful but this warning is bothering me. I checked some other answers but couldn't figure out what's wrong.

Waring - Incomplete implementation

Complexnumbers.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ComplexNumbers : NSObject

-(void) setReal: (double)a;
-(void) setImaginary: (double)b;
-(void) print; // display as a + bi

-(double) real;
-(double) imaginary;

@end
```

Complexnumbers.m

```
#import "ComplexNumbers.h"

@implementation ComplexNumbers  // Incomplete implementation

{
double real;
double imaginary;
}

-(void) print
{
    NSLog(@"%f + %fi",real,imaginary);
}
-(void) setReal:(double)a
{
    real = a;
}
-(void) setImaginary:(double)b
{
    imaginary = b;
}

@end
```

Comment: It seems you want to have two *variables* named `real` and `imaginary`, correct?  Well, you have 2 *functions* called `real` and `imaginary` instead, and since they aren't implemented as functions in your `.m` file, you are getting this warning :).  Follow either of the answers provided that mention making `@property` and `@synthesize` for your variables.

Comment: Correct Mike, it's a bit confusing in the start. Lesson learnt though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't implemented these property getters:

```
-(double) real;
-(double) imaginary;
```

You can either implement them:

```
-(double) real { return _real; }
-(double) imaginary { return _imaginary; }
```

Or let the compiler do it for you by declaring them as properties in the header:

```
@property(nonatomic) double real;
@property(nonatomic) double imaginary;
```

And in the .m file:

```
@synthesize real = _real, imaginary = _imaginary;
```

Where the _'s are the instance members.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jeff. I used an underscore and re-declared them as properties and it worked just the way it should.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that your interface says that there are `real` and `imaginary` methods, but you haven't implemented those. Better yet, let the compile synthesize the `real` and `imaginary` setter and getter methods for you by defining them as properties, and your code is greatly simplified:

```
@interface ComplexNumbers : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) double real;
@property (nonatomic) double imaginary;

-(void) print; // display as a + bi

@end
```

and

```
@implementation ComplexNumbers

-(void) print
{
    NSLog(@"%f + %fi", self.real, self.imaginary);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
#import "ComplexNumbers.h"

@implementation ComplexNumbers  // Incomplete implementation

{
double real;
double imaginary;
}

-(void) print
{
  NSLog(@"%f + %fi",real,imaginary);
}

-(void) setReal:(double)a
{
real = a;
 }
-(void) setImaginary:(double)b

{
imaginary = b;
}
 -(double) real
{
   return real;
}
-(double) imaginary
{
   return imaginary;
}

@end
```

Comment: You have a mistake. The ivars don't have leading underscores.